# Apache and Url Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have 2 main pages. It works like so,

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='menu'></div>
    <div id='content'><?PHP require("content.php"); ?></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then, content.php pulls the "page" from the url, and checks it through a url of "good pages". If not, there is a default. Anyway, the typical url looks like this

- /index.php?page=user&id=1
- /?page=group&id=3

I'm trying to make it look like this

- /user/1
- /group/3

This is what I have for my .htaccess file, which doesn't work 100%. It pulls the correct page, but the css files doesn't seem to be uploaded. It is in /css/ in the main directory as index and content.

***EDIT***

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

I'd like the application to be scale-able if possible.
Thanks!

Comment: When writting a Rewrite rule, the first part is the part `catched` and the second part is the `"transformation"`. But if you want to use vars such as `group` or `id`, you have to make a better regular expression to extract the information on the first part. `^*$/` is retrieving anything from the begin to the end in one var, that's not what you want. You have to extract separately the group and the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to be using either an absolute path to your CSS, or use a `base href` for it, or you can prefix the path to the CSS with a `/` if the path to starts from the root domain.

Your .htaccess is fine, but might want some slight tweak:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w)/([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ahhh. Figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: Now, If I try to go from a page to a page, it says /home/user/1, yet I just wanted to go to the user page?

Comment: Again, as with the CSS ensure you use either absolute links, or a `/` before the link, or assign a `base href` in your `<head>`. A leading `/` is probably the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?page=user&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^group/([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?page=group&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I would limit the initial match regex to `(user|group)` personally.

Answer (score 0):

please try with the following code you can get the values in the `$_GET['page']`. Then you can split the values by `/` and then can get your user name,id etc

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+){0,1}$ index.php?page=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,QSA]
```

In the above code you may want to replace the `/project/` with `/`. It will work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try this *.htaccess* code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

You can now directly access your webpage via..

```
www.yourdomain.com/user/1
www.yourdomain.com/group/3
```

Comment: Sometimes, there isn't a need for an ID. like page = home

Comment: so don't pass id just do `home/`

Comment: ok, it seems as if my css file doesn't get uploaded. Any ideas? I made an edit to my main post.